# Scribe VS SSIS? Why would anyone use Scribe over SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, scribe

> Can someone explain why anyone would use [Scribe](https://www.scribesoft.com/) over [SSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services)?

Scribe is extremely slow and not intuitive at all. What are the advantages of Scribe over SSIS. I can't find anything discussing the comparisons that is newer than 2017. The latest comparison I found was like 2012 which makes it pretty much insignificant since they are both entirely different products since then.

Comment: Do you have a concrete problem or use case that you're comparing the two for? Otherwise this is just soliciting general opinions on two commercial products, which is not a good format for an SO question.

Comment: Yes, in particularly reading records from a .csv file and inserting them into a SQL table is painfully slow in Scribe with very large files vs SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two cents: you wouldn't. SSIS is free and fast (so long as you know what you are doing). Find me any product that can beat that.

Note: this assumes that you are comparing two ETL products together. If Scribe does anything more than ETL then that would need to be factored in. But then, you would want to compare Scribe to other comparable products.